# Tikz Plot Y-Axis values

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

In Tikzi
I need to have y axis drawn from 0 to 1 with tics at 0.2, like 0,0.2.0.4 up to 1.0.
I was able to draw x and y axis but when specifying 0 to 1 range the yaxis shrinks.
Can any one tell me how to set y axis range and how to enlarge this diagram, how i can enlarge it with proper aspect ratio to fit in an article because it appears small in size.
The output i get is like this, value 0 appears twice for x and y axes, which should appear only once.

[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
/% draw x , y lines
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};

% draw x ,y points (Values)
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
   \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};     


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% draw x , y lines
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (5.9,0) node[below left] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,5.9) node[below left] {y axis};
% draw x ,y points (Values)
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}
{
   \draw (\j,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node[below] {$\j$};
   \draw (2pt,\j+1) -- ++ (-4pt,0) node[left]  {$\i$};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
now zero at y-axis is omitted.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko, how can i avoid display of 0.0 at y axis. rest is ok

Comment: @user3696623, ups, I overlooked this. It is corrected now!

Comment: Thanks @Zarko, Any hint how to enlarge image, its too small when included in latex

Comment: @user3696623, really, 6 x 6 cm is not so small :-) . You can enlarge it by scaling, for example `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]` will make image twice as large.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i add labels to x and y axis, or position text in centre of x and y label for information of data. But y axis text should be vertically aligned

Comment: @user3696623, you need to make yourself more familiar with `tikz` package. It has excellent (but huge) documentation, however in the (relative short) tutorials you can learning basic s how to draw with it. Note, this site is not a forum. If you have new problems, please ask new question. In it show, what you try so far and where you stuck.