# Tikz Drawing X-Y plot chart

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I was able to draw plot with x and y axis using Tikzi with help of code provided by member of this site.  [Tikz Plot Y-Axis values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568822/tikz-plot-y-axis-values/568857?noredirect=1#comment1434684_568857)

The code follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% draw x , y lines
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (5.9,0) node[below left] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,5.9) node[below left] {y axis};
% draw x ,y points (Values)
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}
{
   \draw (\j,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node[below] {$\j$};
   \draw (2pt,\j+1) -- ++ (-4pt,0) node[left]  {$\i$};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now how i can add X-label and y-Label (vertically) in center of axes as in any plot.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? See the `pgfplots` package. Super easier and the tick marks are automatic.

Comment: Any news? As I see, so far you not accept any of received answers. Does no one of them deserve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
With pure \verb+tikz+:

\bigskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% draw x , y lines
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- node[below=3ex] {$x$ axis} (5.9,0) ;
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- node[left=3em,rotate=90]  {$y$ axis} (0,5.9) ;
% draw x ,y points (Values)
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}
{
   \draw (\j,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node[below] {$\j$};
   \draw (2pt,\j+1) -- ++ (-4pt,0) node[left]  {$\i$};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
With \verb+pgfplots+: 

\bigskip   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0,xmax=4.5,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.05,
    xlabel={$x$ axis}, 
    x label style={at={(0.55,-0.1)}, anchor=north},
    ylabel={$y$ axis},
    y label style={at={(-0.2,0.5)},rotate=90},
    extra x ticks={0}
            ]
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]